# Magento cordova build error

Tags: cordova, magento2.2

I tried to create the magento android app using cordiva, but I'm getting an error. Please help me to fix this issue.

Also, is it possible in cordova to create a magento app or do I need to create magento app from the scratch using rest API?

This is the [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/) which i referred to build the app

Error :

```
>D:\Workspace-MobileApp\CordovaApp\Test>cordova build android
>Android Studio project detected
>ANDROID_HOME=C:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397
>JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
>studio
>Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>Subproject Path: app
>publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
>The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
>at build_co8src5n5z1qu6tgy409t536u.run(D:\Workspace-MobileApp\CordovaApp\Test\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:143)
>:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor
>:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
>:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
>:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavacNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
>:app:processDebugResources
>:app:generateDebugSources
>:app:javaPreCompileDebug
>:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
>:app:compileDebugSources
>:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>:app:mergeDebugAssetsCould not merge source set folders:  FAILED
>33 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 25 up-to-date
>Error: There were multiple failures while executing work items
>at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:52)
>at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:301)
>at com.android.ide.common.res2.AssetMerger.mergeData(AssetMerger.java:29)
>at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders.doFullTaskAction(MergeSourceSetFolders.java:134)
>at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
>at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:60)
>at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:128)
>at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
>at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:311)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:202)
>at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
>at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
>at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
>at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
>at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
>at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
>at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
>at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
>at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>Caused by: org.gradle.workers.WorkerExecutionException: There were multiple failures while executing work items
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.workerExecutionException(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:186)
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.await(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:178)
>at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.WorkerExecutorAdapter.await(WorkerExecutorAdapter.java:55)
>at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:48)
>... 123 more
>Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
>at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
>at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$2.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:161)
>at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:99)
>at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:87)
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.await(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:176)
>... 125 more
>Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
>at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$2.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:154)
>... 128 more
>Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:107)
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:99)
>at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>... 6 more
>Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>at org.gradle.internal.resources.DefaultResourceLockCoordinationService.withStateLock(DefaultResourceLockCoordinationService.java:40)
>at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService$DefaultWorkerLease.start(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:372)
>at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService$DefaultWorkerLease.startChild(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:383)
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:47)
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:105)
>... 8 more
>FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>* What went wrong:
>Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> There were multiple failures while executing work items
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
>* Try:
>Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>BUILD FAILED in 27m 35s
>(node:40112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>Could not merge source set folders:
>Error: There were multiple failures while executing work items
>at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:52)
>at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:301)
>... 128 more
>Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:107)
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:99)
>at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>... 6 more
>Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>at org.gradle.internal.resources.DefaultResourceLockCoordinationService.withStateLock(DefaultResourceLockCoordinationService.java:40)
>at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService$DefaultWorkerLease.start(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:372)
>at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService$DefaultWorkerLease.startChild(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:383)
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:47)
>at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:105)
>... 8 more
>FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>* What went wrong:
>Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> There were multiple failures while executing work items
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction
>* Try:
>Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>BUILD FAILED in 27m 35s
>at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\Workspace-MobileApp\CordovaApp\Test\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
>at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
>at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
>at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:567:12)
>(node:40112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>(node:40112) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```